# Complicated Relationships Driven View

Tags: views

Drupal 6: Basically I have two content types connected by the Node Reference module. One is "Questions," the other is "Answers".

In the view there are 10 content items under "Questions." When the user clicks the link the title of the "Question" they see the page with the question and the link to create a related answer. I have a rule that sends the user back to the view filled with "Questions" after they save their "Answer."

My goal is to remove the recently answer "Question" from the list of available "Questions" on the view. That way they only see "Questions" they have yet not created "Answers" to.

Using the Relationships option and an Argument based on the UID of the currently logged in user I have been able to filter the "Questions" down to those that have "Answers" attached to them that the user has created. However, what I'm looking for is the opposite. Hide those, and only show the ones that don't have "Answers" that the user has created.

Has anyone ever done something similar to this?